# How can I access Phalcon configuration data in an external library?

Tags: php, phalcon

Within my project, I've created a "core" directory which contains certain classes and methods called throughout the controllers. I've defined a configuration parameters in my bootstrap file like so:

```
private function loadConfig ()
{
    // Bootstrap
    $configFile = __DIR__ . '/../config/config.json';

    // Create the new object
    $config = json_decode ( file_get_contents ( $configFile ) );

    // Store it in the Di container
    $this->di->setShared ( 'config', $config );
}
```

I want to be able to access these configuration values in my "core" classes.

What do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to get a reference to the service you registered with the Dependency Injector. However, to make sure you are getting the same instance of the service and not a newly generated one, then you need to use the getShared method:

```
$this->getDI()->getShared('config');
```

Doing so ensures you are getting the highest performance possible, and minimizing memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

in your controller class, call config by

```
$this->config
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access to the services from any classes which implements `Phalcon\Di\Injectable`

- `Phalcon\Mvc\Controller`
- `Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component`
- `Phalcon\Mvc\User\Module`
- `Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin`
- etc

Examples:

```
$this->getDI()->get('config');

// The same as $this->config
$this->getDI()->getShared('config');
```